# Error Rule not found on RBAC DbManager Yii2

Tags: yii2, rbac

I followed this guide (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) but still got an error.

I have created auth_item, auth_item_chid, auth_assignment, and auth_rule Table

When i add this line to my controller

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {   //mycode ... }
```

i got error ->  Rule not found: author

```
protected function executeRule($user, $item, $params)
{
    if ($item->ruleName === null) {
        return true;
    }
    $rule = $this->getRule($item->ruleName);
    if ($rule instanceof Rule) {
        return $rule->execute($user, $item, $params);
    } else {
        throw new InvalidConfigException("Rule not found: {$item->ruleName}");
    }
}
```

I have assigned the user with a role in auth_item table, the auth_item already have auth_item_chid.
On Yii2 all auth_item should set with rule_name. Thats the different with the previous version.

Comment: Can you show the relevant content of your tables? I guess that is the problem. Do you have an entry in auth_rule?

Comment: i watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFOIUeU-Y74
and i used the query on the video comment block

Comment: Strange that you check for 'createPost' but it does not find 'author'. Please provide the relevant rows of your tables.

Comment: i second that, you are probably missing things in the tables

Comment: I got this error when add an auth_item.
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yii2advanced`.`auth_item`, CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `rule_name`, `data`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('webmaster', 1, '', '', '', NULL, NULL)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend DbManager for fix error

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

class DbManager extends \yii\rbac\DbManager
{
    protected function executeRule($user, $item, $params)
    {
        if (empty($item->ruleName)) {
            return true;
        }

         return parent::executeRule($user, $item, $params);
    }
}
```

And change config/web.php like

```
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\DbManager'
    ],
```